# Is it possible to display the memory from localstorage on my website?

Tags: javascript, memory, storage

I want to show the users how much memory they can use and how much memory they used so far.

For example, something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Its a bit tricky to get a % though:

```
$('#usageDiv').value(((JSON.stringify(localStorage).length * 2)/1024).toFixed(2)+" KB");
```

The *2 is because characters in Javascript are UTF16 (2 bytes per char). 
To get the maximum space, you can basically only "test it". Take a look at [how they do it](https://arty.name/localstorage.html)